# Hard refresh a Safari webpage on an iPad

Tags: safari

Is there a way to do a hard-refresh on Safari on an iPad (in the same way control-F5 might do on windows/Chrome say?) so that all page resources (including javascript files are refreshed without using the cache).

Note, I don't want to keep clearing the website cache ("Clear History and Website Data") via Settings/Safari as this throws out login details at the same time.

Comment: You seem to be able to do it on Mac by clicking in the address bar as though you were going to type a new address, then hitting Enter/Return, rather than the regular refresh icon. Might be worth testing if iOS does the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I force a cache refresh in Safari running on iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74797/can-i-force-a-cache-refresh-in-safari-running-on-ios)

Comment: Thanks Kevin, but no - this assumes you have a keyboard if nothing else; it also talks about clearing history - but that is not what I'm looking for.