# How to clear the cache or do a hard refresh in mobile Safari?

Tags: mobile-safari, refresh

On OS-X it's <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or certain menu options ([How to clear the cache or do a hard refresh in Safari?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12049/how-to-clear-the-cache-or-do-a-hard-refresh-in-safari)).

Is there a way to do this for Safari on an iPhone or iPad?

---

This seems like a duplicate? What do you think? I really don't like force-quit: [Can I force a cache refresh in Safari running on iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74797/can-i-force-a-cache-refresh-in-safari-running-on-ios)

This sounds better: [How to clear browser cache for just one specific site in Mobile Safari?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73153/how-to-clear-browser-cache-for-just-one-specific-site-in-mobile-safari)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done through the Settings: https://www.imyfone.com/iphone-space-saver/how-to-clear-cache-in-safari-on-ipad/

1. Launch the "Settings" app on your iPad through the home screen.
2. Scroll down the menu and select "Safari".
3. Scroll down to the bottom of right hand panel and tap on "Clear History and Website Data".
4. Confirm by tapping "Clear" from the pop-up window.

---

Warning: this wipes every data, save form field values, bookmarks, etc.

Comment: This is very inconvenient, and also it blows away everything else (e.g. bookmarks). What about cache-only clearing?

Comment: @MarsAndBack Sorry if this caused grief for you