# How to delete cookies for a specific site on iOS Chrome

Tags: ios, google-chrome

"[How to delete cookies for a specific site](https://superuser.com/q/366483/74576)" is a good question but seems to be about Chrome on a computer rather than on iOS.

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/73697/53510) seems to be just about iOS Safari (rather than Chrome).

(And [this forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/ecoWu4FKkL4) doesn't seem to have an answer yet.)

I found a note from myself (dated more than 1 year ago) saying that this bookmarklet from http://ostermiller.org/bookmarklets/cookies.html should work, but I haven't been able to get it to work on iOS Chrome today and don't know what my note was referring to.

Any suggestions for how I can clear cookies on iOS Chrome for one particular domain (rather than erasing *all* cookies)?

Comment: I do not think it is a feature that is currently avalable.