# Configure Safari to not ask about cookies every refresh on Stack Overflow

Tags: safari

Every time I visit Stack Overflow on an Apple device using Safari (Mac mini with Safari 16.3 or iPhone with iOS 14), each time I load a page it asks about cookies. It does this no matter what I specify (all, none, custom). What is strange is that this doesn't happen on the other Stack Exchange sites.

I am mostly a Windows and Linux user, so I am not even quite sure where to begin. I know Firefox would work and not to XY this, I just prefer Safari. If there is a terminal command I could use, or if I need to manually create a cookie, at least I could use the site easier on my Mac.

I tried the recommendation at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/73697/503090 but it did not work, and on iPhone the customize popup doesn't work either.

I tried disabling the content blockers specifically for Stack Overflow on the Mac Safari, but that did not make a difference.

Normally I will just google for four hours straight instead of asking, but I can't seem to get a lead. Any hints will help. Do I need to inspect the javascript of the SO page and reverse engineer it, or is there an easier way? Experimental features of WebKit?